# Building files with batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a short batch script, it has to do with discord webhooks. It first asks for a license (Only valid licenses can go past here) and then it asks for a discord webhook. Then it sends a random verification number to the webhook and if you give the right code in the prompt then it will build the file I want it to build, with the right webhook in it. And then it will send the file to the webhook BUT i want the file to be sent as a .exe.

It is possible to build files with batch, but I was wondering how I could build a file which then automatically gets changed to a .exe.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using IExpress to convert to executable applications:

```
 :exe
;set "filename=Sample"
;set "target.exe=%temp%\%filename%.exe"
;set "batch_file=%temp%\%filename%.bat"
;set "bat_name=%filename%.bat"
;set "bat_dir=%temp%\"

;Set "sed=%temp%\2exe.sed"
;copy /y "%~f0" "%sed%" >nul
;(
    ;(echo()
    ;(echo(AppLaunched=cmd /c "%bat_name%")
    ;(echo(TargetName=%target.exe%)
    ;(echo(FILE0="%bat_name%")
    ;(echo([SourceFiles])
    ;(echo(SourceFiles0=%bat_dir%)
    ;(echo([SourceFiles0])
    ;(echo(%%FILE0%%=)
;)>>"%sed%"

:: converting to exe
;%windir%\SysWOW64\iexpress.exe /n /q /m %sed% 
;del /q /f "%sed%"
;goto finishexe

[Version]
Class=IEXPRESS
SEDVersion=3
[Options]
PackagePurpose=InstallApp
ShowInstallProgramWindow=0
HideExtractAnimation=1
UseLongFileName=1
InsideCompressed=0
CAB_FixedSize=0
CAB_ResvCodeSigning=0
RebootMode=N
InstallPrompt=%InstallPrompt%
DisplayLicense=%DisplayLicense%
FinishMessage=%FinishMessage%
TargetName=%TargetName%
FriendlyName=%FriendlyName%
AppLaunched=%AppLaunched%
PostInstallCmd=%PostInstallCmd%
AdminQuietInstCmd=%AdminQuietInstCmd%
UserQuietInstCmd=%UserQuietInstCmd%
SourceFiles=SourceFiles

[Strings]
InstallPrompt=
DisplayLicense=
FinishMessage=
FriendlyName=-
PostInstallCmd=<None>
AdminQuietInstCmd=
DisplayLicense=
FinishMessage=
FriendlyName=-
PostInstallCmd=<None>
AdminQuietInstCmd=
goto finishexe


:finishexe
```

Executable will be located in %temp%.

Comment: I have seen the IExpress. Can I automate the thing you have sent tho? If someone opens it, fills in 2 things, could it then automatically convert and send the file to a webhook. Thanks though.

Comment: @YoooOoOoOOOOOo Of course. At start to input you can use `set /p` to get user input, after that paste the code I sent up, after that I recommend using `curl` to send an attachment to a discord webhook.